# Opaque image hovering with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why this isnt working?

I want the images in the sidebar to go opaque when hovered.

```
//Opaque image hover
        $('#sidebar ul li img').hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0.8}, 500);
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });

<div id="sidebar"><!--Sidebar start-->
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/darkroom.png" alt="Darkroom software" class="png"/></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/download.png" alt="Download" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/features.png" alt="Features"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/prices.png" alt="Prices"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/support.png" alt="support"/></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Boker noted, hover() takes two functions.

Also, you have an extra comma in your animate call. I have a feeling that will affect IE.

This:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.8,}, 500);
```

Should be:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.8}, 500);
```

EDIT: added full ready() implementation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar ul li img').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.8}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: On most browsers that comma shouldn't have any effect, and the rest give you an error.

Comment: @voyager - Just tested it. It breaks in IE7. A few people still use that one.  ;o)

Comment: Please modify your question and post a snippet of relevant CSS and HTML. There must be an error elsewhere.

Comment: Is your hover being called in jQuery's ready() function? Please see updated answer (in a second).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it works. Remember to 'accept' my answer by clicking the checkbox.  :o)

Answer (score 3):

Hover usually takes two parameters, first is mouseenter, second is mouseleave, try:

```
$('#sidebar ul li img').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.8}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 500);
});
```

this assumes that original opacity was .2, you set it to what you want.

Comment: Thanks John, but its not working, even when i take out the extra commas. I even try it with just 'img' but not working?